# How to store page-{id}.php templates in custom folder

Tags: functions, templates

I'm trying to create a custom function on WordPress to store page-{id}.php templates in a folder named "custom-pageid-templates" inside my theme directory. Here's the code I'm using:

```
function custom_page_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'page' ) ) {
        global $post;
        $custom_template_path = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/custom-pageid-templates/page-' . $post->ID . '.php';

        if ( file_exists( $custom_template_path ) ) {
            return $custom_template_path;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_page_template_include' );
```

However, when I create a page-{id}.php template in the "custom-pageid-templates" folder and assign it to a page on WordPress, the template is not used, and the page is displayed with the default template instead.

I have double-checked that the file name and location are correct, and that the template name is specified correctly in the file. I have also cleared my browser cache, but the issue persists.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/

Comment: Your code looked good to me, so maybe your filter is being overwritten by a plugin, so try using a lower priority (i.e. a greater number), e.g. `20` as in `add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_page_template_include', 20 )`. You can also try using `get_queried_object_id()` in place of `$post->ID`.

Comment: yeah, the priority made it. thank you!

Comment: can you write that up as an answer so it can be marked as correct?